# Add a new cronjob to crontab using php

Tags: php, cron

Everytime I run the php -f send-Alarma.php file in command line the script does exactly what I want. I now want to set a cronjob so I used:

```
crontab -e
```

Which command should I use there to run the php script from monday to friday, let's say at 4:30 pm? The command should start like

```
30 16 * * *     /usr/bin/...
```

from there I've chosed many commands but it doesn'work.

The path for my php file is /home/comenzi_ropeco/www/cron/send-Alarma.php

Comment: `php -f /home/comenzi_ropeco/www/cron/send-Alarma.php` should work fine

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron  it's all detailed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your answers, but still didn't work. I found this command

```
30 16 * * 1-5 cd /home/comenzi_ropeco/www/cron/; /usr/bin/php -q send-Alarma.php
```

and now it works perfectly fine. Thanks for all your answers! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

By entering this command into your `crontab`, your PHP file will be executed every Monday - Friday at 1630.

```
30 16 * * 1-5 php -f /home/comenzi_ropeco/www/cron/send-Alarma.php >/dev/null
```

The `>/dev/null` means put all the output in here (which is nothing), ie: delete the output.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I've noticed that it appears in command line the message: "you have mail in var/spool/mail/root

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
30 16 * * * 1-5 php -f /home/comenzi_ropeco/www/cron/send-Alarma.php
```

the '1-5' indicate the day of the week where 0 is Sunday 6 is Saturday